# How do I keep new interns motivated and sincere?

Tags: internship

We are having few interns whom we are paying also.  The guys are good in terms of knowledge. Because we are investing our resources on them we expected they will take training seriously and start giving us output asap.   How do we keep them motivated? Unfortunately after  a month of joining they have started appearing insincere and coming late.  I am investing time with them explaining the advantages and scope of the  technology we are teaching them. But despite this why is that their behavior so casual ?

How do I make sure that they stay motivated in the workplace ?   Where is our mistake ?

Comment: There is too little informations on what you did to be able to answer.  The only things I can say is : it is impossible to have always people staying, it is best to be clear at interview what they will do and what you expect from them. yoiu're taking peoples with almost no professional experience, they might take a try and discover they just don't like it. Finally the environment can play a lot (how organized the project they're working on is, ...).

Comment: Can you explain further how you track an employee's tasks, work output, timekeeping etc.? If you don't do much of these, it's possible they think the work is less urgent / significant than it actually is.

Comment: Are you doing feedback one-on-ones with them? What do they say about their motivation? Do they have meaningful tasks? Do they bear any responsibility?

Comment: @Kozaky, there are few things more demotivating than heavy tracking and timekeeping. Neither interns nor experienced workers will become more motivated and engaged simply because they're tracked.

Comment: @teego1967 I wasn't asking in order to suggest enforcing 'heavy' tracking. If, for example, a task is left without any clear estimate of completion time, some people might interpret this as 'I don't have to try to finish this any time soon.' Some timekeeping can be better than none at all.

Comment: What kind of jobs are they doing as interns? You are talking about technology, but you don't say what field, or what country. Both are important for a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

> Unfortunately after a month of joining they have started appearing insincere and coming late.

Consider you got people who start working for the first time. At first everything is excited and new. Once that is gone intrensic motivation becomes less and they might look less motivated. They need to find new motivation than just `its a new experience` and that might take some time. But also you can give them some reasons to:

- Make them feel useful: You want them to make output, they want to feel useful. Give them a task which they can do that makes them feel like they make difference. Even if you need to help them a in the process. (Alternatively you can make them feel useful by including them in creative sessions with seniors and encourage their input.)
- Training need to be put in to practise, make sure that happens (see point above).
- Make sure they are training at the right level. If its to difficult they nmight lose interest, if its too easy it gets boring. (talk with them about this).
- Provide social moments: coffee, 4pm beers etc, make sure they connect with the other colleagues.
- teach them what it means to be professional: Have a talk with them about coming on time, etc. They have no experience so its important to teach them!

My personal experience is that as an intern your often seen as useless or 'takes to much time to invest in' by everyone in the company. if even the colleague next to you thinks so he is not going to have a relationship with the interns. Making the interns feel they are on an island. Make sure this does not happen.

Comment: This is really good advice. I gave a talk about the non-technical aspects of training new software developers (or anyone new to a specific field, really) at the London Perl Workshop 2017, which I believe is quite relevant, as it makes pretty much the same points as you do. You can [watch it here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMYIwT5w4oY).

Answer (score 2):

Before I get too far into the answer, I am a COBOL programmer. One of my main jobs is training new people. No one is excited to learn COBOL, so I have seen this a lot.

The first thing to do is to try and put yourself in their shoes. If they are interns, that usually means that they are either still in school or just graduated. That means at this point they are considering if this is the right career for them.

When people graduate, a lot of the time they think they will get to work in something super cool, so in the software development world that could equate to game design or something cutting edge.

Now imagine your supervisor and mentor has just told you that you will be working a mainframe primarily coding in COBOL. At first it may seem like a cool challenge, but eventually that novelty will ware off and the intern is left feeling unsatisfied. In my experience this is normal not reflective of the individuals long term behaviour.

What has worked for me in the past is take the intern into a one on one meeting and talk to them. Try to figure out what's going on. In my case, I usually talk to them about how massive our system is and the ramifications of it not working correctly. At this point they start to see just how big of a role they actually play.

If that doesn't work my next course of action is usually to tell them that this behaviour is not going unnoticed and if not changed, will probably affect them getting a job when the internship is over. The other thing to remember is that they are still coming out of the school realm and into the real world. It is likely that they have never been face with true consequence over being late and uninterested. This does not make it OK, but just something to realize. So just talk to the intern and explain to them that this behaviour will affect them being kept.

At the end of the day, if did these things and were not able to get to the root cause, I think you absolutely need to let this intern go an start over. I have seen it time and time again where at the end of an internship, the intern is still behaving as you describe and they kept because someone thinks they can fix it after the fact. If you can't fix it during the internship, its not worth it start over. You may have wasted time training that person, but at least it will be over. If you keep them, you will be wasting a lot more time.